# Angular 4 and laravel jwt-auth error

Tags: angular, laravel-5, jwt

My api routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => ['cors','jwt.auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/test', function () {
        return ['name' => 'anil'];
    });
});
```

I am already logged in laravel jwt token generate

```
login(user: Object): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(SettingsComponent.API_ENDPOINT+'api/v1/login', user)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    let token = response.json().token;
    let userid = response.json().userid;
    console.log("Response token:" + userid);
    if (token) {
      this.token = token;
      this.userid = userid;
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ userid: userid, token: token }));
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })
  .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || { message: "Server Error" }));
}
```

I am save local storage token

How to use this token in nexr url send get method

```
getdata() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
         this.authService.token });
    return this.http.get(SettingsComponent.API_ENDPOINT+'api/v1/test',headers )
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || { message: "Server Error" }));
  }
```

The error I am getting:

> { "error": "token_not_provided" }

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

set the token separate in the local storage 
then
You can do like this:

```
return localStorage.getItem('token') ? JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.getItem(token'))) : null;
```